# redis-cli and value from a file

Tags: redis, command-line-interface

Is it possible to easily set specific value from a file using interactive `redis-cli`?

I'd like to achieve same result as with following Python snippet:

```
with open("some.jpg") as f:
    image_binary = f.read()

rd.hset("some_key", "image_binary", image_binary)
```

Comment: You can write this script in LUA, and call it via redis-cli.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Is it possible to easily set specific value from a file using interactive redis-cli?

Since `-x` reads the last argument from `STDIN`, what about:

```
redis-cli -x HSET some_key image_binary <some.jpg
```

You can then easily retrieve the file as follow:

```
redis-cli --raw HGET some_key image_binary > img.jpg
```

*Note that there is an [extra `\n` character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129052/1688185) at the end.*

Comment: It's not really from within interactive shell, but I guess that's the only way possible with `redis-cli`

Comment: Right: there is no *direct* way in pure shell mode (as far as I know). As suggested above I assume Lua scripting may help if you really need to do that.

Comment: Thanks. For those who want to read a file as a non-last argument, `-X <tag>` is helpful. I'm new to Redis and don't know when `-X <tag>` was introduced. Now it's Redis 7.0. For example, `redis-cli -X foo SET some_key foo EX 100 < some_file.txt`. It puts the content of `some_file.txt` to `some_key`.

Comment: @deltheil I have redis version `3.0.504` which doesn't have the `-x` tag.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach is to feed redis-cli a sequence of commands written in a text file:

```bash
$ cat /tmp/commands.txt
SET item:3374 100
INCR item:3374
APPEND item:3374 xxx
GET item:3374
$ cat /tmp/commands.txt | redis-cli
OK
(integer) 101
(integer) 6
"101xxx"
```

Taken from : [Redis Cli Manual](https://redis.io/docs/manual/cli/)